# mocking a function that accepts **kwargs

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, keyword-argument

I am having trouble mocking a function that accepts **kwargs.  The scenario is I have ClassA (which in my specific case is something I didnt write) and it has a function with **kwargs. ClassB which has an instance of ClassA, and calls the **kwargs function.  I want to test ClassB by mocking the call to Class A's function.

Here is what I have tried so far, and in both of my attempts I ended up with a TypeError.  Is there any way to do this? Should I rethink another aspect of this?

```
import unittest


#a class i have no control over. Has a function accepting **kwargs
class ClassA(object):

    def classFunctionAcceptingKwargs(self, **kwargs):
        return kwargs["a"] + kwargs["b"]

# a mock of the above class
class Mock_ClassA(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.mockclassFunctionAcceptingKwargs = lambda **kwargs: None

    def classFunctionAcceptingKwargs(self, **kwargs):
        #FAILS: TypeError: mockFunctionAcceptingKwargs() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
        return self.mockclassFunctionAcceptingKwargs(kwargs)
        #ALSO FAILS: TypeError: mockFunctionAcceptingKwargs() argument after ** must be a mapping, not set
        #return self.mockclassFunctionAcceptingKwargs(**{kwargs["a"] + kwargs["b"]})

#class B calls the class A kwargs but exposes a function with a dict
class ClassB(object):
    def __init__(self, classA):
        self.classA = classA

    def doSomething(self, dict):
        return self.classA.classFunctionAcceptingKwargs(**dict)

class TestClassA(unittest.TestCase):

    def runTest(self):
        a = ClassA()
        result = a.classFunctionAcceptingKwargs(**{"a":1, "b": 2})
        self.assertEqual(result, 3)

class TestClassB(unittest.TestCase):

    def runTest(self):

        mock = Mock_ClassA()
        def mockFunctionAcceptingKwargs(**kwargs):
            self.assertEqual(kwargs["a"], 1)
            self.assertEqual(kwargs["b"], 2)

        mock.mockclassFunctionAcceptingKwargs = mockFunctionAcceptingKwargs
        b = ClassB(mock)
        b.doSomething({"a": 1, "b": 2})
```

Stack trace:

```
Test Name:  TestClassB
Test Outcome:   Failed
Result StandardError:   
======================================================================
ERROR: runTest (module1.TestClassB)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test\module1.py", line 49, in runTest
    b.doSomething({"a": 1, "b": 2})
  File "C:\test\module1.py", line 28, in doSomething
    return self.classA.classFunctionAcceptingKwargs(**dict)
  File "C:\test\module1.py", line 18, in classFunctionAcceptingKwargs
    return self.mockclassFunctionAcceptingKwargs(kwargs)
TypeError: mockFunctionAcceptingKwargs() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 12.873s
FAILED (errors=1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are calling another function. But if you *must* have an instance attribute `mockclassFunctionAcceptingKwargs` function, then just pass on the `kwargs` dictionary with `**kwargs`:

```
class Mock_ClassA(object):
    # ...
    def classFunctionAcceptingKwargs(self, **kwargs):
        return self.mockclassFunctionAcceptingKwargs(**kwargs)
```

You don't need to call that lambda at all if all you need is for `classFunctionAcceptingKwargs` to exist:

```
class Mock_ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self, mock_result):
        self.mock_result = mock_result
    def classFunctionAcceptingKwargs(self, **kwargs):
        self.called_with = kwargs
        return self.mock_result
```

then just pass in the mocked return value, whatever you need to be passed back to `ClassB` for the test, and afterwards you can check that the right value was passed in too:

```
mock = Mock_ClassA(3)  # to return 3 back to the caller
b = ClassB(mock)
b.doSomething({"a": 1, "b": 2})
self.assertEqual(mock.called_with, {'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```

You may want to use the [`unittest.mock` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) to build a mock object to pass in (available in Python 3, and a [backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) for Python 2 can be installed). It'll let you create a mocked `ClassA` and then use the API to test if the mock was used in the expected manner:

```
try:
    # Python 3
    from unittest import mock
except ImportError:
    # Python 2, backport
    import mock

class TestClassB(unittest.TestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        mockA = mock.Mock(spec=ClassA)  # only accept attributes ClassA also has
        mockA.classFunctionAcceptingKwargs.return_value = 3  # or whatever else you want it to return
        b = ClassB(mockA)
        b.doSomething({"a": 1, "b": 2})
        mockA.classFunctionAcceptingKwargs.assert_called_once_with(a=1, b=2)
```

Demo with `unittest.mock` as the mocking layer:

```
>>> from unittest import mock
>>> class ClassA(object):
...     def classFunctionAcceptingKwargs(self, **kwargs):
...         return kwargs["a"] + kwargs["b"]
...
>>> class ClassB(object):
...     def __init__(self, classA):
...         self.classA = classA
...     def doSomething(self, dict):
...         return self.classA.classFunctionAcceptingKwargs(**dict)
...
>>> mockA = mock.Mock(spec=ClassA)
>>> mockA.classFunctionAcceptingKwargs.return_value = 3
>>> b = ClassB(mockA)
>>> b.doSomething({"a": 1, "b": 2})
3
>>> mockA.classFunctionAcceptingKwargs.assert_called_once_with(a=1, b=2)  # passes, no exception raised
>>> mockA.mock_calls
[call.classFunctionAcceptingKwargs(a=1, b=2)]
```